# Server crashes when making an API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const origin = req.body.origin;
    const destination = req.body.destination;
    const urlOri = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + origin + "&APPID={mykey}"
    https.get(urlOri, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
});
```

I have written this code and I am getting this error:

```
Server started on port 443
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 178.128.25.248:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '178.128.25.248',
  port: 443
}
```

This same code runs on one of my friend's pc same as expected, what to do?

I have tried to do the same via request and axios module as well and I got the same error.

Comment: Your error is a **timeout** that occurs on the fetch to the API. This could be from many reasons, but is pointing either to a slow internet connection, or invalid URL. Try pasting the API URL in your browser. Does it work?

Comment: Check if `origin` and `mykey` variables have values and if these values are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I was using a proxy server.
I disabled it and now it's working fine